# Flask dynamic Google Maps markers (python, postgres, psycopg2)

Tags: python, postgresql, google-maps, flask, psycopg2

I'm creating a Flask app that pulls data from a postgresql database using psycopg2. For the user in each row, the database has latitude and longitude info. I want to dynamically plot the users who are active onto my map using markers with this lat/lng information.

Right now, I can get return active user's coordinates using the following in app.py:

```
def getUserLocation(conn, cur):
   cur.execute("""SELECT latitude, longitude FROM user_list WHERE timestamps >
    (current_timestamp - make_interval(mins := %s))""", [setTime])
   for latitude, longitude in cur.fetchall():
      return latitude, longitude
```

Then this return value is saved as **locations**.

```
myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username,
password=password, dbname=database)
cur = myConnection.cursor()    
locations = getUserLocation (myConnection, cur)
```

Then it's rendered to Jinja like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def mapview():
    return render_template('index.html', locations=locations)
```

This is what my add markers function looks like right now, where I try to call these values, and it doesn't work.

```
function addMarkers() {
  {% for location in locations %}
    var point = {lat: {{ location.lat }}, lng: {{ location.lng }}};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    });
  {% endfor %}
}
```

How can I render these points on the map dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Just pass latitude and longitude, and process the points on the client side like this:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  function initMap() {
    var latlng = { lat: 37.09024, lng: -95.712891 }; // THIS IS CENTER OF THE MAP
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

    function addMarkers() {



    var point = { lat: {{ locations.latitude }}, lng: {{ locations.longitude }} };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point, 
      map: map,
      title: '!',
      url: '', 
    });

    marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<div id="content" style="text-align: center">{{ point.info }}</div>' 
    }); // info of the point

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      //window.location.href = this.url;
      this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      //this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      //this['infowindow'].close(map, this);
    });



  }
}
});
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=YOUR_CODE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Could you explain how do I pass lat and long info from my query?

Comment: Do you use a raw sql?
If you used a SQLAlchemy, I could show you. I myself never use raw sql,  and plus to this, I do not know the schema of your database.

Comment: I tried something similar {% for location in locations%} var point = {lat: {{ location.lat }}, lng: {{ location.lng }}}; but this doesn't work, as my entire map fails to render. Are you sure .lat and .lng should be understandable for Jinja?

Comment: Updated, is that what you're looking for? I'm using psycopg2

Comment: I've tried that but the entire map stops rendering. I think it's because the variables "latitude" and "longitude" aren't returned/passed, it's "location" which has both lat and lng together. Also wouldnt I need a for loop?

Comment: @Sarah, I do not quite understand what you are submitting to the template engine for rendering.
I see that you return the longitude and latitude from all users, but this is a function of sampling from the database, and I want to see what you are transferring directly to the client's side, in the jinja

Comment: I've edited the question, you can refer to the third block of code. So I'm passing the variable/result "locations", which is the combined lat & lng info.

Comment: I run into a different error: It says TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable regarding the {% for location in locations %}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147208/discussion-between-narnik-gamarnik-and-sarah).

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake.
You can not iterate an object in a template as I indicated.
But for this, you need to transfer the center point on the map.

Comment: Hi, yes I posted in our chat, not sure if you saw it! But yes I got a solution :)

Comment: @Sarah, publish your answer, others may find it useful